# Why are Azure Container Apps capped at 2 cpu cores total?

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

Been looking into azure container apps and their limits make no sense.

[image]

They say a total of 2 cpus for all container instances of this app and what does that mean? It seems it's some kind of a limit total for revisions not for apps in a container apps environment.

Why? This limit makes no sense or the wording is weird.

Answer (score 1):

> They say a total of 2 cpus for all container instances of this app and
> what does that mean? It seems it's some kind of a limit total for
> revisions not for apps in a container apps environment.
>
> Why? This limit makes no sense or the wording is weird.

As per the [current quota limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/quotas), the maximum number of cores allocated for each container app replica is 2 vcpu and we can have around 20 containers app per environment.

If you want to increase the quota for your container apps you need to [raise a support ticket](https://azure.microsoft.com/support/create-ticket/).

Comment: How does having 2 images in a single app work? What is its purpose? 
Is this limit also affecting the revision routing (ie if pod is 2 cores, there are is split traffic?)?

Answer (score 0):

It's worth mentioning that there are certain limitations on requests for quota increases. For instance - you can't increase the number of revisions you can run per container app or the vCPU cores per replica even if you raise a support ticket.